# Logarithm of a matrix: inequalities

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Let A, B, C, D be positive semi-definite matrices and $\alpha$ a real number between zero and one.

It is fulfilled:

$Tr(A \log(B)) \geq Tr(A \log(C))$,

where $Tr$ is a trace. Does from this follow:

a) $Tr(A \log(B+D)) \geq Tr(A \log(C+D))$

b)$Tr(A \log(\alpha B)) \geq Tr(A \log(\alpha C))$

c) $Tr(A \log(B+A)) \geq Tr(A \log(C+A))$

?

I would be also grateful for naming me some literature which can me help with these problems. "Topics in matrix analysis" wasn't helpful (or I have missed something).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have found an answer for part b): Yes.

The proof:

We use [the following property of the matrix logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix#Properties):

$\log(GF)=\log(G)+\log(F)$,

where $G$ and $F$ commute. Accordingly, where $F$ will be in our case $\alpha 1$ (where 1 is identity matrix, so it commutes with everything)

$Tr(A\log(B)) \geq Tr(A\log(C)) \Rightarrow$

$Tr(A\log(B)) + Tr(A\log(\alpha 1))  \geq Tr(A\log(C)) + Tr(A\log(\alpha 1)) \Rightarrow$

$Tr(A\log(\alpha B)) \geq Tr(A\log(\alpha C)).$

According a) and c): No, as the matrices

$
a=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0.584421 & 0.295001\, +0.310138 i \\
 0.295001\, -0.310138 i & 0.415579 \\
\end{array}
\right)$,

$b=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0.385804 & 0.286079\, -0.213992 i \\
 0.286079\, +0.213992 i & 0.614196 \\
\end{array}
\right),$

$c=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0.688838 & 0.37651\, -0.227299 i \\
 0.37651\, +0.227299 i & 0.311162 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

does not satisfy c).